# Get My location using Kivy or CLI?

Tags: java, javascript, android, python, kivy

I am creating a app for android using Kivy (python) that will send my location to a email. But kivy is not able to do this as GPS is not directly supported. This is what I have thought as my next step, but I need help.

1. Is there any CLI command that can give me my location. I will run that command using os.system(commad), the basic method for running commands in python.
2. Is there any executable available, like a jar file, or a javascript file, that I can run from my code and that gives me my current position using GPS.
3. Any readymade code of Kivy or Java, that I can test on my Phone.

Answer (score 0):

Kivy uses [python-for-android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android) to compile APKs for you. It also provides [pyjnius](https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius) to wrap Android/Java API calls. This lets you access things like the Location API. The [Plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer) project is a cross platform layer that uses pyjnius for the Android part. There is a [GPS example](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/tree/master/examples/gps) in Plyer which you can compile and use on Android if you have Kivy and Buildozer set up properly. Or you can read [the source code of the GPS for Android part of Plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/plyer/platforms/android/gps.py) to make your calls via pyjnius.

Comment: This is looking promising. Should I need to install plyer on my android device? Currenly only Kivy is installed.

Comment: You need to compile an APK via python-for-android or buildozer. Plyer will be included in that APK.

Comment: Is there nothing that can help with Kivy alone? I can't get any executable file anywhere?

Comment: The GPS support in Plyer is as simple as it gets with Kivy.